# Chat Application with RecyclerView in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using the RecyclerView in my chat application. I get the chat list from the API.

If i send any message it is not updated in the RecyclerView. If i go back and come to that activity it updated in the RecyclerView. I used the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` isn't working.

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<LiveChatGetMsgResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LiveChatGetMsgResponse> call, Response<LiveChatGetMsgResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    LiveChatGetMsgResponse resp = response.body();
                        //Here i get the message list, i send this list to adapter class
                        msg_list = resp.getData();
                        myLinear=new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this);
                        myLinear.setReverseLayout(true);
                        recyclerChatList.setLayoutManager(myLinear);
                        adapter = new LiveChatListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), msg_list);
                        recyclerChatList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    //i use this method to scrroll down the RecyclerView
                        scrollToBottom();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LiveChatGetMsgResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("LiveChatGetMsgFailure",t.getMessage());
            }
        });

private void scrollToBottom() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (adapter.getItemCount() < 1)
        recyclerChatList.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerChatList, null, adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth are you setting a new adapter  and new layout manager each time you get a response?

Answer (score 1):

You can have an updateData method inside your adapter, like this

```
public void updateData(List<YourItem> yourItems){
     mData.clear();
     mData.addAll(yourItems);
     notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

to avoid creating a new adapter, just because data has changed, in each iteration.

Also avoid to set up everything in each iteration

```
// Delete these lines
myLinear=new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this);
myLinear.setReverseLayout(true);
recyclerChatList.setLayoutManager(myLinear);
adapter = new LiveChatListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), msg_list);
```

Try it and let us know if it solved the problem.

Comment: In the onResponse method:  updateData(resp.getData);

Answer (score 1):

if it's you are the sender, maybe you can add this function :

```
.... adapter{
    public void addItem(CustomClass customClass){
         yourListOfObject.add(customClass);
         notifyItemInserted(yourListOfObject.size()-1);
    }
}
```